# Add new Nextcloud Calendar from same account

Tags: 18.10, calendar, online-accounts, nextcloud

I have a Nextcloud running. On the Webinterface I added a new (actually the third) calendar on my Account. I want to sync it with *gnome-calendar*. The "old" two, including my personal calenadar are listed on "manage calendars", but not the new one.

Can I force gnome to update the calendarlist without removing my nextcloud-account?

---

Edit: The day after the calendar was loadet. Does anybody knows why and how to sync it manually?

Answer (score 1):

Even though this question had been asked long ago, I stumbled over the same problem right now.

Gnome-Calendar wasn't syncing my new calendar from Owncloud/Nextcloud.

As I did not find any solutions, I just deactivated the calendar sync at the Online-Account Settings for Nextcloud and activated it immediately again. Before I did so, I closed Gnome-Calendar.

After the above I started Gnome-Calendar again and voilà the new calendar was automatically synchronized as well as all other already existing calendars.

Just in case anyone else wonders how to get it to sync new calendars.